# GoogleCloud Error: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

When I deploy `Angular` project to `gcloud`, all the pages can be loaded normally, but when I refresh the page, I will get the error as the title, or if I access it directly by typing the URL, it will be wrong, and I can only access it from the homepage to not make the later pages wrong, this problem has been bothering me for a long time.

My route is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/search/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'search/home', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'search/:ticker', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'watchlist', component: WatchlistComponent },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
];
```

My app.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: nodejs20

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/stock-app/browser/index.html
  upload: dist/stock-app/browser/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: dist/stock-app/browser
```